# pytest fails when run in folder which has __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

The folder where `pytest` command is run has `__init__.py` inside. That's why tests fail to import modules from `utils`. This behaviour is in line with pytest requirement stated in the [docs](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-package-name) that `basedir` should not contain `__init__.py`.

Is there a way to run `pytest` in a directory with `__init__.py` in it?

Below is the folder structure.

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── tests
└── utils
```

If `__init__.py` is removed from the folder, `pytest` succeeds.

Comment: Why not run pytest from a different directory?  It's true that if you're trying to run a package, and the base directory of that package isn't on your `sys.path`/`PYTHONPATH` then indeed package-relative imports won't work correctly.

Comment: in which directory you suggest to run it? i would stumble on the same issue because of pytest behaviour: `determine basedir: this is the first “upward” (towards the root) directory not containing an __init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is adding below code to the test modules inside `tests` folder:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../../')
```

Then, running `pytest` inside folder `tests` works. (it still fails if run inside root project folder.